# Send byte array to client

Tags: axios, quarkus

I got it working to send a multipart-form-data to the server.

Clientside:

```
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append( 'name', uploadName );
    data.append( 'file', file ); //File is in the format UInt8Array

    Ajax( keycloak, {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'server/certificateDownload2',
            data: data
        },
        callbackFunction
    );
```

Serverside:

```
@POST
@Path( CERTIFICATE_DOWNLOAD2 )
@Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
@Produces( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA ) //Not sure about this type ?!?
public JrxmlDTO certificateDownload2( @MultipartForm JrxmlDTO dtoImportieren ) {
    return dtoImportieren; //For testing I am return immediately received DTO
}
```

This is my responseDTO:

```
@Data
public class JrxmlDTO implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private byte[] file;
}
```

But how can I receive this byte[] correctly on the client to save it as file again?

```
async function jrxmlDownloadCallback( response: AxiosResponse, certificateName: string ) {
  //response.data.response.file is a very long string
  //string is "3N4F928LCDJK...."
  const test = new Uint8Array( response.data.response.file );
  //After "new UInt8Array" my test-variable is an empty UInt8Array ??
  //How do I correctly convert the string to an correct UInt8Array?

  //The following gives me a string representing the uInt8Array
  // "120, 330, 13, 120, ..."
  //But how can I use this String as input for `new UInt8Array`?
  const uInt8ArrayAsString = atob( response.data.response.file );
  const UInt8Array = new Uint8Array ([uInt8ArrayAsString]); //Not working: new Uint8Array is awaiting a `ArrayBufferLike`

  const blob = new Blob( [test] );
  FileSaver.saveAs( await blob, 'test.jrxml' );
}
```

How can i correctly download the bytearray from the server?

Do I have to set on the server the `@Producer` property to `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`, `Application_JSON`?
Do I have to parse anything on the client to get a blob?

Comment: I am a bit confused from the question; if I understand correctly, what you want is to POST form data, fill-in a document (PDF? probably using Jasper Reports?) and send that document (PDF?) to the client. If this is the case, you need to specify the `@Produces` to the MIME type of your document (e.g. `application/pdf`). I do not know how Axios is handling binary responses, but usually what happens is that you get some kind of [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) in the client. There are facilities and libraries to save that `Blob` to disk.

Comment: I want to save jasper reports (*.jrxml, not pdfs) in my database and download it when needed. I post the jasperreport as UInt8Array to the server. I save this into my database. I have a postgres database and the file is stored as "bytea". (Up to here it is working) Now I want to download this file again and I have no idea how it works. Do I have to convert the byte[] from the database to base64, send it to the server and convert it back to UInt8Array? Looks complicated and I have read that converting to base64 is only a workaround

Comment: I think the first step is to get the file as binary (`byte[]`, `InputStream`, etc) in Java. Then, in order to send a byte stream to the client through JAX-RS, you have to make your method return `byte[]`, `InputStream`, or `StreamingOutput`.

Comment: I have updated my initial post with my DTO. I am returning already a byte[] as file. But I think the `@Producer` on the serverside is wrong. Do I have to return the byte[] in json format? Any other format? Do I have to parse anything on the client side?

Comment: OK, seeing the format of the data you want to return I understand. You want to return some more data, along with the bytes. For cases like this, I remember the `byte[]` is transported in a base-64 encoded string. In my case I did something like what you did in your answer. (I guess you could send the file name as a header, even making use of the `Content-Disposition` standard header, and send the pure bytes in the response body, saving some network bandwirdth. But that is an optional optimization.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution. I'm just not sure if there isn't a better way.

On the server, set the MediaType to Application Json:

```
@POST
@Path( CERTIFICATE_DOWNLOAD2 )
@Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) **//I changed to Application JSON**
public JrxmlDTO certificateDownload2( @MultipartForm JrxmlDTO dtoImportieren ) {
    return dtoImportieren; //For testing I am return immediately received DTO
}
```

On the client we have first to decode the base-64 encoded string. After that convert the string to numbers:

```
async function jrxmlDownloadCallback( response: AxiosResponse, certificateName: string ) {
    const uInt8Array222 = atob( response.data.response.file ); //Decode base64 encoded string
    //Now we have UInt8Array as string: "60,93,50,..."
    //Parse this to numbers:
    const uintArray = new Uint8Array( uInt8Array222.split( ',' ).map( function ( eineZahl: any ) {
        return parseInt( eineZahl );
    } ) );
    const blob = new Blob( [uintArray] );
    FileSaver.saveAs( await blob, certificateName + '.jrxml' );
}
```